# Scala equivalent for Groovy @Slf4j annotation

Tags: scala, groovy, slf4j, traits

Migrating from Groovy to Scala here. So far I really like Scala, however I am instantly missing my `@Slf4j` annotation, where I could just have:

```
@Slf4j
class Fizz {
    void doSomething() {
      log.info("We're doing something now...")
    }
}
```

...and Groovy would create an SLF4J logger and inject it into `Fizz`'s bytecode for me. It spared me from having to do the following in **every single** class:

```
class Fizz {
    Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Fizz)

    void doSomething() {
      log.info("We're doing something now...")
    }
}
```

I *really* miss this so far.

I'm wondering if I can use traits/mixins to do the same, but it would have to be generic so I could use it with *any* class:

```
trait MyLogger[T] {
    def log = Logger.getLogger(T)
}
```

Then:

```
class Fizz extends MyLogger[Fizz] {
  def doSomething() : Unit = {
    log.info("Doing something now...")
  }
}
```

etc. Is this possible to do? If so, am I close or way off base here?

Comment: It could be implemented by [macro annotation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/annotations.html)

Comment: Alternatively `lazy val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass.getName)` would spare you the need to pass a type parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, you're on the right track with your trait:

```
trait Logging {
  lazy val log = Logger.getLogger(getClass.getName)
}
```

You use it like this:

```
class MyStuff extends MySuperClass with Logging {
  log.info("Setting up my stuff")
}
```

In fact, this is pretty much what [scala-logging](https://github.com/typesafehub/scala-logging/blob/1e289c62fa3d962d2cf72ded49cfc09dbad09f69/src/main/scala/com/typesafe/scalalogging/Logging.scala) does - plus a few more macros to save you typing the `if (log.is_LEVEL_Enabled) log._LEVEL_` (but still putting it in the final output).

Comment: Thanks @Sean Vieira (+1) - just curious why the logger has to be `lazy`?

Comment: It doesn't @smeeb - it just avoids creating one at all if you mix `Logging` into a class that never logs.